# Password regex validation always erroring

Tags: jquery, regex

I have the following custom jQuery validation regex which should be making sure that passwords are at least 8 characters long, have a number and contain no spaces:

```
$.validator.addMethod("password", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /\A(?=.*\d)\S{8,}$/i.test(value);
}, "Password must have at least one digit, be 8 characters in length and not contain spaces.");
```

However not matter what I type into the box, it always calls the error. Is the regex incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS `\A` doesn't mean *start of string*, use `^` instead:

```
/^(?=.*\d)\S{8,}$/i
```

See MDN [boundaries doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#boundaries)